# delete mysql with laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, sql-delete, information-schema

I need to delete information from the database through a submit post.
But it updates and does not delete information.

Route:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::post('/home/linha/insert', 'HomeController@insert')->name('home');
Route::post('/home/linha/remove','HomeController@deletar');
```

Controller:

```
    public function deletar(Request $request)
{


    $id = $request->input('id');

     DB::delete('delete from linha where id = :id' ,['id' => $id]);


      return redirect('home');


}
```

View:

```
<div class="col-md-9" style="margin-top:20px;">
    <div class="col-md-9"><?php echo "$linha->msg"; ?></div>
    @if($linha->iduser == auth()->user()->id)
    <div class="col-md-3"><form action="/home/linha/remove" method="post">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="{{$linha->id}}">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remover 
        </button>
        </form>
        </div>@endif
</div>
```

Comment: You need to ask your question in English on this site, please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676

Comment: define your route as `Route::delete('/home/linha/remove','HomeController@deletar');`

Comment: @TharakaDilshan that won't work if the form's method is set to `POST`

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? There is no code given to update anything. Additionally, the Eloquent documentation shows another notation for deleting models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This: It was shown in Laravel Documentation as well.

```
$deleted = DB::delete('delete from linha where id = ?',[$id]);
```

Here is link of Documentation  ( https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database ).

Or You Can Use laravel eloquent "linha"

```
$request->YourModel()->findOrFail($id)->delete();
```

Comment: I tested it already, it does not return error just from a refresh on the page.

Comment: Would you please let me know what error it giving you?

Comment: I put dd ($ deleted); and responds 0.

Comment: it means that there is no action performed. Do you have data in that table? Can you please do `dd(  $request->input('id'));` and what let me know what you get?

Comment: It worked but I saw that it is not getting the correct input id.

Everyone is returning id 1.

Answer (score 3):

There is a multiple way to delete records in Database (there is no syntax error in your query)

follow this statement for debugging

you should use `dd(DB::getQueryLog());` and you get raw query & execute this raw query in database manually

1st way (by eloquent )

```
$linha= linha::find($id);
$linha->delete();
```

2nd way

```
DB::table('linha')->where('id', '=', $id)->delete();
```

3rd way

```
DB::delete('SQL QUERY HERE');
```

for more information read [laravel delete manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#insert-update-delete)

Comment: 1ª $id = $request->input('id');
    $linha= DB::find($id);
    $linha->delete();

Comment: @Noscin i have update my answer, you should use 2nd way and follow my instruction on top the answer for debugging

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be like this:

```
 DB::delete('delete from linha where id = ?' ,[$id]);
```

Its just the syntax.

Alternatively, you can use this line:

```
 DB::table('linha')->where('id', $id)->delete();
```

Comment: I tried and it happened the same thing, update but not delete.

Comment: Option 2, refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
public function deletar(Request $request){

    $id = $request->input('id');
    if( \DB::table('linha')->where('id', $id)->delete() ){
        // deleted successfully
    }

    return redirect('home');
}
```

Comment: I tried and it happened the same thing, update but not delete.

Comment: Whats the output of `dd(\DB::table('linha')->where('id', $id)->get());` ?

Comment: Collection {#284 ▼
  #items: []
}

Comment: Since collection is empty, it means there is no matching entries in your DB table "linha" matching that id. 
what about `dd($request->id);` ?

Comment: Request->id = "1"

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in Laravel:

1. Soft Delete - updates the deleted_at column.
2. Run query to delete particular id of the table, I think this can work for you.

Comment: Just formatted your answer. Hope you don't mind... ☺

Comment: How does this answer the question? Can you show code that solves the given problem?